# Custom height Bootstrap's navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a header with a height of 150px which contains a navbar. The navbar should be vertically centered in the header.

**HTML**:

```html
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container" style="background:yellow;">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-th-list"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="/"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" /></a>
                <nav class="nav-collapse collapse pull-right" style="line-height:150px; height:150px;">          
                    <ul class="nav" style="display:inline-block;">
                        <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**:

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 150px;
    color:red;
    height: 150px;

    .navbar-inner {
        border:0;
        border-radius: 0;
        background: blue;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        height: inherit;
    }
}
```

The nav/menu/vertical list is now in the top right of the header. How do I get it to center vertically? bootstrap.css is uncustomized.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

your markup was a bit messed up. Here's the styles you need and proper html

**CSS**:

```css
.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

**HTML**:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Or check out the fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/TP5V8/1/

Comment: Thanks! This works, but with this code a new problem arises: when i shrink my window the navbar turns into a button. Unfortunately nothing happens when I push the button. Any idea on that?

Comment: yeah that's just the collapseable bootstrap nav just remove the button tag an enclosed code if you don't want that effect

Comment: I did want the effect. It was just that when I tapped the button, nothing happend. Somehow got it fixed.

Comment: You don't need `padding-top:0`. Just make your line-height value half.

Comment: This will also make any dropdown menus in the navbar this tall. You can fix that by changing the second selector to `.navbar-nav > li > a`

Answer (score 12):

You need also to set `.min-height: 0px;` please see bellow:

```
.navbar-inner {
    min-height: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

If you set `.min-height: 0px;` then you can choose any height you want!

Good Luck!

Answer (score 5):

For Bootstrap 4, there are now [spacing utilities](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/) so it's easier to change the height via padding on the nav links. This can be responsively applied only at specific breakpoints (ie: `py-md-3`). For example, on larger (md) screens, this nav is 120px high, then shrinks to normal height for the mobile menu. No extra CSS is needed..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse bg-primary navbar-toggleable-md py-md-3">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item py-md-3"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item py-md-3"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item py-md-3"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item py-md-3"><a href="#" class="nav-link">More</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item py-md-3"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Options</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Bootstrap 4 Navbar Height Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/sX5c2jOteO)

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are using Bootstrap 3. If so, please try this code, here is the [bootply](http://bootply.com/92542)

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="background:yellow;">
            <a href="/">
                <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo img-responsive">
            </a>

            <nav class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right" style="line-height:150px; height:150px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="display:inline-block;">
                    <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Nope, this is not it. This way, the logo is on the top left and the menu is on the bottom right.