# How to customize the height of bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the height of Twitter Bootstrap Navbar to 24px height.
I have tried the code in Bootply, and there the height is changing, but when I try it in my project the minimum height is 40px;

I need this navbar on 24px height: I found the other topic [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837444/custom-height-bootstraps-navbar), with this answer, but did not worked for me:

```
.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Please see the code here, and tell me what am I doing wrong?

[CODE HERE](http://www.bootply.com/129226#)

Comment: I found the other topic, but I couldn't make it work

Comment: the issue was setting additional `min-height: 0px;` along with the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have defined somewhere else in your CSS `min-height:40px;` for the navbar. Find it and erase it or you can just override it by including `min-height:0px;` in the CSS for your navbar.

Try:

```
.navbar-inner {
background: none;
filter: none;
border: none;
font-family: 'Calibri';
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: #000;
height: 24px !important;
min-height: 0px; //ADD THIS
}
```

Comment: That worked out great for me! thx!

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
.navbar-inner {
background: none;
filter: none;
border: none;
font-family: 'Calibri';
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: #000;
height: 24px !important; /* here */
}
```